# Pixi.js - Unable to set sprite width to full width of canvas

Tags: html, pixi.js

Ultimately I want to have a canvas that fills the entire viewport width of the browser and have an image on the canvas fill the entire width of that canvas. I'm taking advantage of pixi.js's displacement filter so that I can create a pseudo 3d effect using a depth map underneath it. The code I'm currently using is

```
let app = new PIXI.Application();
var w = window.innerWidth;
var h = w / ratio;
app.view.style.width = w + 'px';
app.view.style.height = h + 'px';
document.body.appendChild(app.view);
let img = new PIXI.Sprite.from("images/horses.png");
img.width = w;
img.height = h;
app.stage.addChild(img);
depthMap = new PIXI.Sprite.from("images/horses-depth.png");
depthMap.renderable = false;
depthMap.width = img.width;
depthMap.height = img.height;
img.addChild(depthMap);
app.stage.addChild(depthMap);
displacementFilter = new PIXI.filters.DisplacementFilter(depthMap, 0);
app.stage.filters = [displacementFilter];
```

Here's a screenshot of it in action.
[image: black canvas with smaller image inside]
I even tried manually setting the width to the viewport pixel width on the canvas and the sprite to the actual pixel width of the viewport width and it still wasn't the right size. Manually setting the width for the viewport and sprite to the exact same number also doesn't work; the sprite is inexplicably smaller than the canvas.
I tried to look at the documentation of the sprite class and see if there is something unusual about how sprites handle widths but I couldn't find anything https://pixijs.download/dev/docs/PIXI.Sprite.html
How can I create a pixi.js sprite that fills the entire width of the canvas in order to make both the canvas *and* the sprite fill the entire viewport width?
pixijs.download
PixiJS API Documentation
Documentation for PixiJS library

Comment: I'm not an expert but I would recommend you look into scaling the image.